# If cell number in certain dataframe column is equal to or greater, insert duplicate row and add balance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data-frame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['number'] = (651,651,651,4267,4267,4267,4267,4267,4267,4267,8806,8806,8806,6841,6841,6841,6841)
df['name']=('Alex','Alex','Alex','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Abhishek','Abhishek','Abhishek','Blake','Blake','Blake','Blake')
df['hours']=(8.25,7.5,7.5,7.5,14,12,15,11,6.5,14,15,15,13.5,8,8,8,8)
df['loc']=('Nar','SCC','RSL','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNI','UNI','UNI','UNKING','UNKING','UNKING','UNKING')
print(df)
```

For each row that has hours between >=10 and <=12, I need to:

1. change the total of the hours of the current row to 10
2. insert a duplicate row to the above and add the balance of hours to this row

For each row that has hours >12

1. change the total of the hours to 10
2. insert below a duplicate row to the above and 2 hours to this row
3. insert another duplicate row to the above and add the balance of hours to this row

The result of the new dataframe should look like the following:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with *the **balance** of hours* ?

Comment: for instance the first row for Abhishek is 15 hours therefore this row needs to change to 10 , then a row is inserted with 2 hours and another row is inserted with 3 hours to meet the 15 hours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Code

```
# subset the dataframe based on hour value
s =  df[df['hours'] < 10]
s1 = df[df['hours'] > 12]
s2 = df[df['hours'].between(10, 12)]

# Assign duplicate rows per subset and concat
pd.concat([
    s,
    s1.assign(hours=10), 
    s1.assign(hours=2), 
    s1.assign(hours=s1['hours'] - 12),
    s2.assign(hours=10),
    s2.assign(hours=s2['hours'] - 10)]
).sort_index(kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
```

#### Result

```
    number      name  hours     loc
0      651      Alex   8.25     Nar
1      651      Alex   7.50     SCC
2      651      Alex   7.50     RSL
3     4267     Ankit   7.50  UNIT-C
4     4267     Ankit  10.00  UNIT-C
5     4267     Ankit   2.00  UNIT-C
6     4267     Ankit   2.00  UNIT-C
7     4267     Ankit  10.00  UNIT-C
8     4267     Ankit   2.00  UNIT-C
9     4267     Ankit  10.00  UNIT-C
10    4267     Ankit   2.00  UNIT-C
11    4267     Ankit   3.00  UNIT-C
12    4267     Ankit  10.00  UNIT-C
13    4267     Ankit   1.00  UNIT-C
14    4267     Ankit   6.50  UNIT-C
15    4267     Ankit  10.00  UNIT-C
16    4267     Ankit   2.00  UNIT-C
17    4267     Ankit   2.00  UNIT-C
18    8806  Abhishek  10.00     UNI
19    8806  Abhishek   2.00     UNI
20    8806  Abhishek   3.00     UNI
21    8806  Abhishek  10.00     UNI
22    8806  Abhishek   2.00     UNI
23    8806  Abhishek   3.00     UNI
24    8806  Abhishek  10.00     UNI
25    8806  Abhishek   2.00     UNI
26    8806  Abhishek   1.50     UNI
27    6841     Blake   8.00  UNKING
28    6841     Blake   8.00  UNKING
29    6841     Blake   8.00  UNKING
30    6841     Blake   8.00  UNKING
```

Comment: I added your code under my original code however the output didn't change and certainly didn't achieve your output. What am I missing

Comment: Make sure you are assigning the result of `pd.concat` back to some variable for e.g. `df`?